# Unite two variables in document.write javascript

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have two variables:

```
var a = 'aaa';
var b = 'bbb';
```

I would like to output them using only one document.write like:

```
aaabbb
```

How could I unite them in document.write? I need something like $a.$b in php.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody forbids you to use `+` (can be used to concatenate strings) :)

```
document.write(a+b)
```

Another variant is

```
document.write(a.concat(b))
```

Comment: @Max You can check the checkmark below the votes count of my answer to mark this problem as solved ("accept answer").

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `+` is used to concatenate strings; it works like `.` in PHP:

```
a + b
```